# Magento is not saving customer address

Tags: magento2, magento-2.1

I have tried 2 kind of solutions

> //First kind----------------------------------

```
$addresss = $objectManager->get('\Magento\Customer\Model\AddressFactory');
$address = $addresss->create();

$address->setCustomerId($customer->getId())
->setFirstname('vinoth')
->setLastname('kumar')
->setCountryId('IN')
//->setRegionId('1') //state/province, only needed if the country is USA
->setPostcode('31000')
->setCity('Osijek')
->setTelephone('0038511223344')
->setFax('0038511223355')
->setCompany('GMI')
->setStreet('Kersov')
->setIsDefaultBilling('1')
->setIsDefaultShipping('0')
->setSaveInAddressBook('1');
try{
$address->save(); echo'asdasd'; exit; //Not saving data. Refreshes the page. Not printing the echo.
}
```

> // Second kind ---------------------------------------

```
public function __construct(
        \Magento\Directory\Model\Region $region
        \Magento\Customer\Api\Data\AddressInterfaceFactory $addressDataFactory,
        \Magento\Customer\Api\AddressRepositoryInterface $addressRepositoryInt
    ) {
        $this->_region = $region;
        $this->_addressDataFactory = $addressDataFactory;
        $this->_addressRepository = $addressRepositoryInt;
    }

    public function updateAddress($custId){ echo $custId;
        $directory = $this->_region->create();
        $addressIntFct = $this->_addressDataFactory->create();

            $addressIntFct->setCustomerId('id here')
            ->setFirstname('firstName')
            ->setLastname('lastName')
            ->setCountryId('US')
            ->setPostcode(98089)
            ->setCity('city')
            ->setTelephone('999999999')
            ->setFax('999999999')
            ->setCompany('company')
            ->setStreet('street')
            ->setRegionId('region id here')
            ->setIsDefaultBilling(1)
            ->setIsDefaultShipping(0);
            ->setSaveInAddressBook('1');
            try{
                $this->_addressRepository->save($addressIntFct); echo'asdasd'; exit; //Not saving data. Refreshes the page. Not printing the echo.
            }catch (Exception $e) {
                Zend_Debug::dump($e->getMessage());
            }
    }
```

**No exception or errors are in log file.**

Any idea why its not working?

Answer (score 1):

First solution worked fine except of that you don't have a `catch` for the `try`.

Second solution worked fine after fixing, the `setStreet()` expects an array as param and not a string, unnecessary semicolon on `setIsDefaultShipping()` and there is no function `setSaveInAddressBook()` defined in

```
vendor/magento/module-customer/Api/Data/AddressInterface.php
```

so you have to use `->setData('save_in_address_book', '1');`

Comment: can you update me setStreet code ? how you have used it, i am also facing same issue

Comment: @jafarpinjar this is how you can get setStreet working `$address->setStreet(['my address']);`